# Tor loop issue to this mess

Tags: firefox, error-handling, tor

So I have been using Tor browser for a while now and a some time ago I encountered an issue

I started getting the 'There is already a Tor browser open, close it to start a new Tor' message, (I know isn't what it says but it makes sense) thing is, I didn't have another Tor open! This began around the time I switched over to Firefox so I think there might be some conflict between the two browsers so a fix for that will be helpful if this crops up again. Jumping to about a week or two ago, when I try to open Tor, I get this error message:

[image]

I don't want to delete Tor because I have a a lot of saved pages on it! Can you please provide any fixes to these issues? Thanks in advance!

edit: I am planning on switching to ubuntu very soon, but I want to make sure Tor is working beforehand, so this more of a Tor windows fix, some advice on converting Tor from windows to linux would be very handy! Thanks again!

Comment: Are you using Firefox with Wine that it is an .exe file or are you asking on the wrong page?

Comment: Or am I wrong and that the Linux version of Tor needs the Windows version of Firefox to work?

Comment: please [edit] your question with details of your version of ubuntu.